# Beginner Question - How do I get my JS code to show on a browser?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, browser

I'm using VS code as my code editor (not sure if it's relevant). My first project is on Changing Background Color. Once I'm done writing my codes, how do I get them to show on a browser?

I'm not sure how to get it to show on a browser.

Comment: You can try out the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension. This will live preview your JavaScript and HTML code.

Comment: I really feel like this doesn't need a whole answer block... just link your javascript file into your html and open up your .html file. `<script src="C:/full/path/to/script.js"></script>`. You don't need a server to render .html files. Maybe I'm wrong tho.

Answer (score 0):

You want see your code in browser you will open live server of the code docoument -

open a HTML file and right-click on the editor and click on Open with Live Server .

or just type this url in browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/
```

5500 is a default port

or  just install an extensions live server it will directly open the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opnion to execute JavaScript in your browser is to put it inside a script element inside an HTML document.
I mean that in the same folder that you have the js file, create an html file and in there put the script link of the file.

```
 <script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

This need to be in the `<head></head>`

Answer (score -1):

hi in vscode download live server then click html file with right click and open with browser